# Recursive i itialization and how to use config group inside another config group

Tags: fb-hydra

I am exploring the options of the recursive initialization in hydra. I was able to setup a working example based on [this PR](http://%20https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/pull/989/commits/6ac5a6270530ff4acf76248a01e11c3cc4278847). When trying more advanced stuff, I stumbled upon the following problem. My directory structure is as follows:

```
config/
  config.yaml
    /tokenizer
      Tokenizer.yaml
    /normalizer
      Normalizer.yaml
```

The configs contain:

```
<config.yaml>
default:
  - tokenizer: Tokenizer

<Tokenizer.yaml>
_target_: some.path.Tokenizer
normalizer: Normalizer # I want this to be the Normalizer object after instantiation, but getting string. 

<Normalizer.yaml>
_target_: some.other.path.Normalizer
arg1: value1
```

I want to recursively instantiate the Tokenizer without the need to explicitly write all the arguments of the Normalizer since all of them are already mentioned in the Normalizer.yaml file. In other words, I would like to use the normalizer config group inside tokenizer config group. Right now, if I call `tokenizer = instantiate(cfg.tokenizer)`, the result is a Tokenizer class object, but `tokenizer.normalizer` is a string `Normalizer`. If I use value interpolation and setup the project as follows:

```
<config.yaml>
default:
  - tokenizer: Tokenizer
  - normalizer: Normalizer

<Tokenizer.yaml>
_target_: some.path.Tokenizer
normalizer: ${normalizer} 

<Normalizer.yaml>
_target_: some.other.path.Normalizer
arg1: value1
```

The resulting variable `tokenizer.normalizer` is a dict containing args for Normalizer like so`{"_target_": ...}` instead of being an initialized Normalizer class. How can I avoid the need to explicitly repeat the definition of the normalizer inside the tokenizer config?

Comment: It will help if you show your actual final config and now what you do to compose it.

Comment: Hi, thansk for response. The config above are basically what I use. I compose the config with the default main decorator mentioned in the basic tutorial. Maybe the question is more like how to use group config option in another group config and how to use recursive instantiation in such case. I will reformulate once i get to my pc

Comment: @omry I edited the question to make more sense. There were some parts missing. Is it now nore understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want is supported right now.
Please file a feature request with a minimal config, and an explanation of the current behavior and the desired behavior.